# Extract two links at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, embedly

I am working with a service called [Embedly](http://embed.ly/), which makes it possible to 'enrich' ones links in the page. The people at embedly have made it possible to call there API with jQuery.

So first one has a link like this:

```
<a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-24692392">bbc</a>
```

Then you call the API to do the magic like this:

```
var hr = $('a').prop('href');

$.embedly.extract([hr], {key: '672cb2dfbc7249f2beb67db44204a39c'})
  .progress(function(result){
    $('body').html(result.content);
  });
```

The problem is that I can't seem to process two links at the same time. If you look at this example at [JsFiddle(link)](http://jsfiddle.net/wwkhR/2/) you will see only one link is being processed. I tried solving this with jQuery `each` and calling the two links as different variables but the API always processes the last url. How do I get it to process multiple URL's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im more of a javascript guy so here you go...

```
var link=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<link.length;i++)
{
    $("a").css("visibility","hidden");
    $.embedly.extract([link[i].href], {key: '672cb2dfbc7249f2beb67db44204a39c'})
  .progress(function(result){     
    document.body.innerHTML +=result.content;      
  });
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wwkhR/6/)

Comment: Thanks:) This is (almost) exactly what I was looking for. I can now refer to all the links but I notice the API is still being called twice while there docs say it can request 20 in a batch so thats kinda weird. Also do you have any idea why this doesn't work: `$('body').html(result.content);`

Comment: `.html` sets the html of the `body` to `result.content`. It doesn't `append` to the end of the html. If you want to use jQuery, you use `$('body').append(result.content);`

Answer (score 2):

i don't know embedly but i am seeing that you are assigning the result to the body html, this may works.

html:

```
<a id="a0" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-24692392">bbc</a>

<a id="a1" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-24699733">bbc</a>
<div id="resultA"></div>
<div id="resultB"></div>
```

js

```
var hr0 = $('#a0').prop('href');
var hr1 = $('#a1').prop('href');

$.embedly.extract([hr0], {key: '672cb2dfbc7249f2beb67db44204a39c'})
  .progress(function(result){
    $('#resultA').html(result.content);
  });
$.embedly.extract([hr1], {key: '672cb2dfbc7249f2beb67db44204a39c'})
  .progress(function(result){
    $('#resultB').html(result.content);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wwkhR/5/

Comment: Thank you very much:) This actually crossed my mind but I was trying to avoid this because Im dealing with 20 urls so I would have two make 20 calls to the API instead of just one in batch